# DB2 get a list of numbers in a range

Tags: sql, db2

Apologies if this seems too simple. I cannot seem to solve it.

I am trying to get numbers from 20000001 to 21000000 but it is only giving me one value. If I change numbers to 10 and 0 , I get numbers from 1 to 10.

```
WITH A(Num) AS
(
    VALUES (1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NUM+1
    FROM A
    WHERE Num <= 21000000 and Num > 20000000
)
select Num from A
```

Answer (score 2):

You should understand how Recursive Common Table Expression works in Db2 to realize what you did wrong...
Try this:

```
WITH A(Num) AS
(
    VALUES 20000001
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NUM + 1
    FROM A
    WHERE Num < 21000000
)
select Num 
from A
--fetch first 10 rows only
;
```

Comment: Just a note. In my experience, for a small range of values a recursive CTE works well. However, if the query needs to produce 1 million rows (as in this example) it's much more performant to write a function/procedure that feeds a pipe.